# C++ - access variables on static void functions

Tags: c++, variables, undeclared-identifier

This is my callback-function (ALOG is for debugging)

```
static void playerEventCallbackA(void *clientData, SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent event, void *value) {
    ALOG("###################### CALLBACK PLAYER A.... ");
    if (event == SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayerEvent_LoadSuccess) {
        ALOG("###################### CALLBACK PLAYER A.... loaded"); 
        SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer *playerA = *((SuperpoweredAdvancedAudioPlayer **)clientData);        
        playerA->setBpm(126.0f);
        playerA->setFirstBeatMs(353);
        playerA->setPosition(playerA->firstBeatMs, false, false);
    };
}
```

i need to set the bpm here, which i have detected on a other function in this class. How can I manage this?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What do you actually want to achieve by accessing there per-object variables in a function which does not work on objects?

Comment: I have edited the question above ;)

Comment: There is no *the* `bpm`, that's the whole point. When `bpm` is a non-static data member, each object (instance) of that class has its own value of `bpm` and there is no "global" one. A static member function, on the other hand, is not associated to any one object - it's basically a global function. It can access the `bpm` value on any object, but you must know which object's value you want to change. Or do you want `bpm` to be static as well (a global value)?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, since `static function` has no `this` parameter. You can access only static members, or send object of needed type to static function.

Answer (score 0):

You have either to pass an object of the class to the function and use within the function the data members of the object or to create an object of the class as a local variable of the function and access the data members of the object.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
private:
    float a, b, c;
public:
    A( float a, float b, float c ) : a( a ), b( b ), c( c )
    {
    }

    static void display_average( const A &a )
    {
        std::cout << ( a.a + a.b + a.c ) / 3 << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   A a( 10.10f, 20.20f, 30.30f );

   A::display_average( a );
}
```

Comment: it is a pre-defined callback-function .. is there a workaround?

Comment: @GeneralError  It is an example that demonstrates how a static function can deal with objects of the class.

Comment: thank you for the example. i still can't get it to work :/ (i'm very new to c++) .. i have edited the question above with the function

Comment: @GeneralError From your edited post it is not clear what is the problem with playerA->setBpm(126.0f);?

Comment: i have detected the value dynamicly in a other function.. now i want to set it via `setBpm()` in the `playerEventCallbackA()`